Density of Schwartz distributions in the space of distribution
Let $\mathscr S(\mathbf R^3)$ and $\mathscr D(\mathbf R^3 )$ be the space of  Schwartz function and test function respectively, $\mathscr S'(\mathbf R^3)$ and $\mathscr D'(\mathbf R^3)$ be their duals.
I want to understand what the phrase "$\mathscr S'(\mathbf R^3)\subset\mathscr D'(\mathbf R^3)$ and the inclusion is dense" means.
$\mathscr S'(\mathbf R^3)$ is a space of distributions so obviously $\mathscr S'(\mathbf R^3)\subset\mathscr D'(\mathbf R^3).$
Now we focus on the density. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denote the duality braket.
Question: is $\mathscr S'(\mathbf R^3)$ dense in $\mathscr D'(\mathbf R^3)$,  meaning that $\forall T \in\mathscr D'(\mathbf R^3)$ there exists a sequence $T_n$ in $\mathscr S'(\mathbf R^3)$ such that $\forall \psi \in \mathscr D(\mathbf R^3)$ we have $\langle T_n , \psi\rangle \to \langle T, \psi \rangle$?

Usually Schwartz distributions refers to elements of $\mathscr{D}'$, elements of $\mathscr{S}'$ are "tempered" distributions. The former is endowed with a topology, the density you refer to is with respect to that topology.

Yeah I agree, and for the strong dual topology on $\mathscr D'(\mathbf R^3)$ what you are asking is true, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics).

$\mathcal S'$ is not literally a subset of $\mathcal D'$ since these distributions act on different spaces of test functions. Rather, a $u\in\mathcal S'$ has a unique continuous extension to $\mathcal D\supseteq \mathcal S$ and can be naturally identified with an element of $\mathcal D'$ in this way. This issue and your actual question are discussed in all the standard sources on the subject, and I believe your question would have been better suited for (and likely better received at)  https://math.stackexchange.com/ .
